# Why is a templated function parameter resolved but not a templated return type?

Tags: c++, templates

I had the following bits of code:

```
int APIENTRY _tWinMain(_In_ HINSTANCE hInstance, _In_opt_ HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, _In_ LPTSTR lpCmdLine, _In_ int nCmdShow)
{
    int serialport = getCommandLineOption<int>(lpCmdLine, "-com", atoi);
    ...

template<typename T>
T getCommandLineOption(const std::string& commandLine, const std::string& option, std::function<T(const char*)> f)
{
    auto result = getCommandLineOption(commandLine, option);
    return result.empty() ? T() : f(result.c_str());
}

const std::string getCommandLineOption(std::string commandLine, std::string option)
{
    ...
```

and then I removed the include of the `functional` header and changed the template function to:

```
template<typename T, typename F>
T getCommandLineOption(const std::string& commandLine, const std::string& option, F f)
{
    auto result = getCommandLineOption(commandLine, option);
    return result.empty() ? T() : f(result.c_str());
}
```

now in `WinMain` where I call the function to get the serial port parameter I cannot omit the int type specification but I *can* omit the function pointer type specification. why?

PS: the `getCommandLineOption` functions are in a static library, the static library is used by the project that contains the `WinMain`.

Comment: You may remove `T` and use `std::result_of` to get the return type.

Comment: In the former, `T` could be deduced from the last parameter of your function. In the latter only `F` can be deduced from function parameters. Hence, you have to specify `T` explicitly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Return type cannot be deduced by compiler. You may use:

```
template<typename F>
auto
getCommandLineOption(const std::string& commandLine, const std::string& option, F f)
-> decltype(f(getCommandLineOption(commandLine, option).c_str()))
// or decltype(f(declval<const char*>()))
{
    auto result = getCommandLineOption(commandLine, option);
    return result.empty() ? decltype(f(result.c_str())){} : f(result.c_str());
}
```

[Live example](https://ideone.com/ctZACg)

Comment: this yields: error C2893: Failed to specialize function template ''unknown-type' getCommandLineOption(const std::string &,const std::string &,F)'
With the following template arguments:
'int'

Comment: You don't have to specify `<int>` anymore as the return type is dictated by `F`.

Comment: but then it says getCommandLineOption' : function does not take 3 arguments

Comment: I just added a live example.